# Loading several .php file into one div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Hello i have this code to load php file into div. Its working but i need load next file into this div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a.load").on("click", function(load) {
            load.preventDefault();
            $("#zaw").hide().load(this.href).fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });
</script>

<li><a class="load" href="zzz.php">zzz</a></li>
```

If i click "zzz" link loading file into my div (file table with images) i need hide this page and load next by click image.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a.load").on("click", function(load) {
            load.preventDefault();
            $("#zaw").hide().empty().load(this.href).fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: need more clarification

Comment: Click link "zzz" to load file "zzz.php" to div #zaw
(zzz.php content its table with images)
And i need by clicking image unload "zzz.php" and load other file

Comment: then you can give an id to the image like <img id='remove'
then use jquery 
$("#remove").click(function(){
$("#zzz").html('');
});

Comment: hope you got my point

Comment: Something like that ?
http://jsfiddle.net/kjyaroxt/

Comment: My English is not very good so I drew
http://imgur.com/AaxdV3z

Comment: Don't add answers as an edit to your question. Instead, answer your own question via the answer section with what you have learned. You can even accept your own answer! This way everyone can see that the question has a working answer, without even clicking the link to the page, and is the answer on a pre-defined spot on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simply need to bind another click event to an image (or table body) that you load through `load()` function. However, you may experience some issue with your click not working, and heres why:

If you attach two click handlers, one for `a.load` and second for, let's say, `.image` than only the first event will actually get bind to its element, and the socond one won't be attached because, well, `.image` doesn't exist yet - not untill you load it.

You could expect, that once you php file content will get loaded (with `.image` elements in it), then clicking them will fire an action you have declared, but it won't - those `.image`'s are new DOM elements and they missed an event binding procedure which was done only once when the DOM was created (or DOM was ready if you use `$.(document).ready()`).

So, in order to get those clicks to work you need to either attatch them on `load()` function callback, like so:

```
$("a.load").on("click", function(load) {
        load.preventDefault();
        $("#zaw").hide().load(this.href, function(){
            $(".image").on("click", function(e) {
            $("#zaw").hide().load(/* load what you want */);
        });
    })
    .fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

or insert `.image` click event binding inside php file you are loading or use some sort of delegation, for example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.image', function(){
    /* do what you want */
});
```

which will make sure that even new, dynamically created DOM element will fire an action you want.